# Render Nunjucks macro in AJAX call on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nunjucks, eleventy

I am trying to render data from a JSON file on the front end using AJAX (I am also using Eleventy, Nunjucks, and jQuery), and it would save a lot of headache + time to be able to use a Nunjucks macro (which I have already created) to render the information being returned instead of recreating the entire component (it would save future time and effort too as the code used wouldn't have to be edited twice).

Here is the code for that is creating the JSON data:

```
// AJAX Call for Posts
config.addCollection("post", async function (collectionApi) {

    // get unsorted items 
    let allPosts = await collectionApi.getFilteredByTag("post");

    // Loop through and only get the data you need from each post 
    let curatedPostData = allPosts.map(post => {
        return {
            title: post.data.title,
            description: post.data.description,
            image: post.data.image,
            url: post.url
        }
    });

    // Filter out any null values 
    curatedPostData = curatedPostData.filter(post => post);

    // Create a new file in your project 
    fs.writeFileSync("_data/ajax-list.json", JSON.stringify(curatedPostData))
});
```

Ideally, this would work for the AJAX call but it is not currently:

```
$("#showMorePostsButton").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url: "/js/posts-list.json", success: function(result){

    // Output results from AJAX call
    $("#displayPosts").html( 

    // Import the Nunjucks macro
    {% from 'components/cards/postCard.njk' import postCard %}

    // Use the macro with information from AJAX call
    {{ postCard(postTitle = title, postDescription = description, postImage = image) }}
    );

  }});
});
```

Would anyone know how to get this snippet working and use a Nunjucks macro on the frontend somehow with Eleventy, Javascript, or Nunjucks itself?

Any and all suggestions are very much appreciated, thanks

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/little-brother/c06114cf73cddfca1372c04e3e138867) is an example how to use nunjucks in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [js data files](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-js/) to load data from your api.

Comment: AFAIK these will only compile at build time, I'm using AJAX so that it can run in the browser as it'll greatly increase my website speed and performance

Comment: If you want to use nunjucks in runtime with 11ty, you need to precompile templates to js files, to be able to bundle it to your js, and use it later.

Comment: Would you be able to add an example? I'm having a hard time trying to imagine what this would look like.

Comment: It depends of what your setup looks like. If you use just 11ty w/out any task-runner for bundling your JS, than you need to decide on this setup first, because it would be used to transpile nunjucks templates.